# Windows 2003 DNS subdomains

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

We have a purely internal DNS setup to resolve multiple nics for eash host, i.e. -

- mailserver01-sm 1.1.1.1 remote access and AD connectivity (service management)
- mailserver01-data 2.2.2.2 mail routing
- mailserver01-bk 3.3.3.3 backup connectivity

My question is this can I frig DNS by having sub domains of -sm, -data, & -bk under the FQDN ?

so that the following each appear under the relevant subdomains:-

- mailserver01-sm.datacenter.int
- mailserver01-data.datacenter.int
- mailserver01-bk.datacenter.int

instead of:-

- mailserver01.-sm.datacenter.int
- mailserver01.-data.datacenter.int
- mailserver01.-bk.datacenter.int

Answer (score 2):

Having any part of an FQDN starting or ending with a hypen is not a supported configuration. You can create a zone starting or ending in -, but it's really not recommended.

Also, records within that zone (i.e. A or CNAME) that start with a - will not work with most DNS resolvers, as - is usually reserved for flags.

You can use _ however.

Refer to [RFC 1035](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt), section 2.3.1 (although it's been revised by [RFC 1123](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1123.txt) to permit starting with a digit rather than an alpha)